# Using CodeMirror for single-line expression editing

Tags: codemirror

Is CodeMirror a good choice to implement a one line expression editor? I can't figure out from the manual (or the questions I reviewed) if CodeMirror can be configured to do the following:

- Display no scrollbar (text should slide to the left if too long to fit)
- Ignore attempts to insert a new line
- I do need syntax checking & highlighting and auto-completion on a predefined set of variables & operators, so a DSL editor would definitely make things easier

If CodeMirror is not a good match are there alternatives I should consider?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"JQuery Terminal Emulator is a plugin for creating command line interpreters in your applications." Try it: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php

Comment: And you can use `$.cmd` sub plugin that is inside. It have only one line editing, but you will be able to insert new line if you paste text from clipboard and it don't scroll to the left but wrap around the text into multiple lines.